# How can I optimize this MySQL query, select rows that are NOT IN another table

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        IGN,
        MAX(aktualizacja) AS wywalony,
        DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MAX(aktualizacja)) AS wywalony_dni_temu
    FROM dump_armijny
    GROUP BY IGN
) AS a
WHERE IGN NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT IGN
    FROM dump_armijny
    WHERE aktualizacja =
    (
        SELECT MAX(aktualizacja)
        FROM dump_armijny
    )
)
ORDER BY wywalony DESC
```

but it takes ~2 seconds on a 13k rows table, and it grows very fast, how can I optimize it?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing the structure of the tables you are querying and how they are indexed.

Comment: Also, you can run `EXPLAIN {your query}` and learn quite a bit if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT IGN, MAX(aktualizacja) AS wywalony, 
             DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(aktualizacja)) AS wywalony_dni_temu
      FROM dump_armijny
      GROUP BY IGN
     ) a
WHERE IGN NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT IGN
                  FROM dump_armijny
                  WHERE aktualizacja = (SELECT MAX(aktualizacja)
                                        FROM dump_armijny
                                       )
                 )
ORDER BY wywalony DESC;
```

Typically `not exists` is more optimized than `not in` and `select distinct` is unnecessary in an `in` subquery anyway.  I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT IGN, MAX(aktualizacja) AS wywalony, 
       DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(aktualizacja)) AS wywalony_dni_temu
FROM dump_armijny a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM dump_armijny a2 JOIN
                        (SELECT MAX(aktualizacja) as maxa FROM dump_armijny) m
                        on aktualizacja = m.maxa
                   WHERE a.IGN = a2.IGN
                 )
GROUP BY IGN
ORDER BY wywalony DESC;
```

It is a bit hard to follow the logic of the query, but I *think* this is the same as:

```
SELECT IGN, MAX(aktualizacja) AS wywalony, 
       DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(aktualizacja)) AS wywalony_dni_temu
FROM dump_armijny a JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(aktualizacja) as maxa FROM dump_armijny) m
GROUP BY IGN
HAVING wywalony <> m.maxa
ORDER BY wywalony;
```

In any case, you should define some indexes.  A "must-have" is `dump_armijny(aktualizacja)`.  For the `not exists` version, you also want `dump_armijny(IGN, aktualizacja)`.

Comment: Thanks! I added some indexes and it takes 0.2 sec now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dump_armijny.IGN is indexed.